# How should I use font awesome icons to have the highest performance for my website?

Tags: css, performance, fonts

I am using font awesome on my web application.
Although I use only one icon in one of my pages, all fonts will be downloaded which increase page load time.
And as you see in the image(the second font file) it's 80KB and takes 3S to load.

[image]

is there any way to decrease its file size and load time?

is it a good idea to subset it?

how about using SVG?

Comment: https://icomoon.io/, create own font

Comment: maybe base64 would be good? Idk how you load tho.

Comment: Use a CDN to download from https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: I am including the min.css file but in my css folder. Do you suggest me to use CDN instead? is CDN faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use icomoon as suggested for loading time.

For rendering time if you have icons that repeat a lot in the page, like in a table you can use what font awesome calls symbols.

```
<i class="fas fa-edit" data-fa-symbol="edit"></i>
<i class="fas fa-trash" data-fa-symbol="delete"></i>

<div>
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-w-20"><use xlink:href="#edit"></use></svg>
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-w-20"><use xlink:href="#edit"></use></svg>
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-w-20"><use xlink:href="#edit"></use></svg>
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-w-20"><use xlink:href="#delete"></use></svg>
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-w-20"><use xlink:href="#delete"></use></svg>
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-w-20"><use xlink:href="#delete"></use></svg>
</div>
```

[source](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/performance-and-security)